# Revisions of Spanish orthography / ¿Qué revisiones ha tenido la ortografía española?

Tags: historia, ortografía, rae, preguntas-canónicas

> This is a [canonical question](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2505/1674) / Esta es una [pregunta canónica](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2505/1674)

Recent [repeals of long-standing orthographic rules](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/11/26/world/europe/26spanish.html) in Spanish have gotten me curious.  I know of the latest revision, dated 2010.  I know of the 1999 revision.  I have seen references to a 1959 set of revisions.  What about earlier revisions to the orthographic rules?  Where would I find out about them, and the changes they made?

---

Las [recientes derogaciones de reglas ortográficas largamente presentes en español](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/11/26/world/europe/26spanish.html) me han producido curiosidad.

Conozco las revisiones de 2010, las últimas. También las de 1999. Vi referencias a las de 1959. ¿Qué hay de las anteriores revisiones a las reglas ortográficas? ¿Dónde puedo encontrarlas, así como los cambios que introdujeron?

Comment: The link goes to a previous comment to the 2010 edition. No recent reviews. Apocalyptic predictions were unsuccessful...

Comment: I added a canonical question!  Cool!  Does that give me a special prize?  Can I henceforth be known as "the canonical student"?  (Of course, @guifa would be then known as "the canonical teacher").

Comment: @ltcomdata - Sure!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Well, the first bit is knowing what the different editions are:

- **1741** [Orthographía española](http://www.rae.es/sites/default/files/Ortografia_RAE_1741_reducida.pdf)

  - Initial alphabet of 24 letters <sub>(ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ)</sub>

    - U and V considered variations of the same letter
    - J called *i jota*, Z called *zeta* or *zeda*
    - Ç rejected as a letter, to be replaced by *z*
    - W called *walima* rejected as a letter, foreign words with it to be pronounced as *vv* as vowel-consonant (that is, *uv* /ub/)
  - Began use of *x* for /ks/ <sub>(but rejected /gs/)</sub>
  - Rejection of the spelling *ll* for /l/
  - Rejection of double consonants (except for *ss*, and *cc*/*mm*/*nn* when pronounced as such)
  - Absolute distinction of *r* /ɾ/ and *rr* /r/, except for word-final (always *r* /r/)
  - Circumflex on vowel after *x* /ks/ or *ch* /k/ <sub>(*reflexîona*, *chârácter*)</sub>
  - *c* instead of *q* before *u* except when etymology dictates otherwise.
  - *qu[aou]* and *qü[ei]* is /ku̮/ <sub>(*qu[ei]* is /k/)</sub>
  - *z* before *e* or *i* when etymologically sensible.
  - Rejection of apostrophe for synalepha
  - Description of Spanish numbers <sub>(as opposed to Roman or Arabic, seriously, these are mega awesome cool, look on pages 86-87, or pages 110-111 in the PDF)</sub>
  - Initial accent rules:

    - No accents on monosyllabic words
    - Accents always on words stressed on the antepenultimate syllable (*esdrújula*)
    - Words ending in *A*, *E*, *O*, *S* stress penultimate.  Accent otherwise.
      <sup>Exception: words ending in *N* follow this rule when they are third-person plural forms of verbs

      Exception: Don't remove accents when pronouns added to verbs
      Exception: Don't remove accents when making adverbs</sup>
    - Words ending in *I*, *U* stress ultimate.  Accent otherwise.
    - Words ending in *Y* stress ultimate.  No exceptions.
    - Words ending in consonants stress ultimate.
      <sup>Exception: Surnames *-az* and *-ez* stress penultimate.</sup>
    - Preposition *á* and conjunctions *é*, *ó*, *ú* always accented.
    - Comma has a space before it <sub>(not specified, but shown)</sub>
  - NB: There's a cool listing of handwriting and letter formation at the end on PDF pages 383-395 worth checking out.
- **1754** [Ortografía de la lengua castellana](http://bivaldi.gva.es/es/consulta/registro.cmd?id=6648)

  - Introduction of *¿* and *¡* punctuation marks <sub>(just to disambiguate, not required)</sub>
  - Added letters CH *che*, LL *elle*, and Ñ *eñe* to the alphabet <sub>(“oops we left them out before”, they said)</sub>

    - J also called *jota*, U deemed *u vocal*, V called *v consonante* <sub>(U/V still considered one letter with two forms, though)</sub>
  - Removed the “erudite” spellings <sub>(their words in the 1803 intro, not mine)</sub>, mainly *th*, *rh*, *ch* /k/ and *ph* but not completely
  - Simplification of *rr* to *r* after *l*, *n*, or *s* and at beginning of words.
  - For the handful of *ch* /k/ words left, circumflex no longer needed on following vowel.
  - K is now explicitly for foreign words only.
  - *Qua*, *qüe* pronounce u, all others silent.
  - Accent rule modifications:

    - Addition of accents on monosyllabic words that may not by diphthongized <sub>(*dé, sé, etc.*)</sub>
    - Accents also on preantepenultimate syllables
    - Presumption of penultimate stress — only mark ultimate stress
      Exception: Words ending in DLNRXZ stress ultimate, except foreign words and names ending in -EZ
      Exception: The rules for S became a giant clusterf***
- **1763** [Ortografía de la lengua castellana](http://books.google.com/books?id=Wns--sK0UrgC&dq=1763%20Ortograf%C3%ADa%20de%20la%20lengua%20castellana&pg=PP17#v=onepage&q&f=false)

  - Simplification of accent rules
  - Simplification of *ss*, *ſs*, *ſſ* and *ß* to *s*
  - Also *s* is only *s* and doesn't alternate with *ſ*
  - Only Hebrew/Greek names to use *ch* /k/
  - Standardization for spelling of toponyms and surnames.
  - Cultismos with *hie-* become -ge-
  - Introduced rules for Latin *f* to Spanish *h conversion

    - *h* always if *-ue-* comes next, or a vowel comes next, and especially between two vowels
    - *h* if it's been reduced to a "mayor suavidad"
    - *hie* or *ye* depending on whether pronunciation has a semivowel or semiconsonant (see next rule)
  - *i* normally for semivowel, *y* as semiconsonant, etymology be damned <sub>(no unstressed i betwixt vowels)</sub>

    - Exception: use *y* for rising diphthongs except for *vosotros* conjugations and *ui* combinations
    - Exception: use *Y* when capitalized <sub>(Probably to avoid confusion with lowercase *L*)</sub>
  - /χe/ and /χi/ written *ge*/*gi* except for certain names and when *-jo* or *-ja* get suffixes attached
  - Established rules on the use of *X*
  - Omit *p* before *t* or *s* if not pronunciation, but
- **1770** [Ortografía de la lengua castellana](http://books.google.com/books?id=HWgVAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA173#v=onepage&q&f=false)

  - The preferred spelling of /χ/ is *ja, ge, gi, jo, ju*, unless there's an etymologic or overwhelming popular use to the contrary (Latin *s* becomes *x*, for instance) and word finally
  - *in-/en-* prefix on *m-* words no longer becomes doubled *m*
  - *-mp-* changed to *n* to match pronunciation (*redempción* to *redención*)
  - First time *u* and *v* (“de corazón”) are considered separately.
  - Accent rules modified:

    - No accents on monosyllables, except for when two different ones vary by their separation to other words (te vs té), or for single vowel words (but not *y*)
    - Next-to-last syllable stressed when ending in vowel absent an accent
    - Accent next-to-last syllable if it was a verb form with pronouns added
    - Consonant + two vowels treated as two syllables unless accent on the second vowel (*frio* /fri.o/ vs. frió /frjo/)
    - Accent all words 3+ syllables that end in *ee, ia, ie, ua, ue, uo* depending on where stress falls, no accent means they are diphthongs
    - Presume that words ending in *ae, ao, au, ea, eo, oa, oe, oo* stress the first vowel, accent otherwise
    - Words ending in *y* with final stress need no accents
    - All consonants stress final syllable, but still write accent for *-ás/-és/-ís* in verbs (because you don't adjust accents for plural, so *-s* normally is penultimate)
    - *-ez* patronym still counts for penultimate syllable.
  - Use ... or ::: for clipped text.
- **1775** Ortografía de la lengua castellana
- **1779** [Ortografía de la lengua española](http://books.google.com/books?id=hZeol5B90wYC&pg=PA38#v=onepage&q&f=false)

  - (Some of these changes may have occurred in the 1775 edition)
  - Quo /ko/ and *qüo* /kwo/ now distinguished, but more often written with *c*
  - More *ch* /k/ words rewritten as *c* or *qu* leaving just the most jarring ones (Biblical, mainly).
  - *fi-* that changed variably to *hi-* or *y-* is now always *hi-*.
- **1792** [Ortografía de la lengua castellana](http://books.google.com/books?id=Hl7RaABmvOEC&dq=1792%20ortograf%C3%ADa%20de%20la%20lengua&pg=PP5#v=onepage&q&f=false)

  - No significant changes
- **1803-1806** (Diccionario de Autoridades y por conferencias)

  - Addition of CH *che* /tʃ/ and LL *elle* /ʎ/ to the dictionary for sorting
  - Complete simplification of *ch* /k/ to *c* or *qu*
  - Complete removal of *ph* (always *f*)
  - Conversion of *k* to *c* or *qu*
  - Conversion of *x* /χ/ to *j* or *g*
  - Respelling based on actual pronunciation especially for now-silent letters.
  - Distinction of *y* as consonant, *i* as vowel (“with exceptions” according to the 1820 prologue, see 1815)
- **1815** [Ortografía de la lengua castellana](http://books.google.com/books?id=0A8lKPhEpXIC&lpg=PR10&ots=1ZikQvEq5N&dq=Ortograf%C3%ADa%20de%20la%20lengua%20castellana%201763&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false)

  - Confirms and codifies the changes made in the DdA and the conferences
  - J called exclusively *jota*, Z only *zeda*
  - I now called *i vocal* and Y is *y consonante* (matching U/V)

    - The only time *y* is used as vowel is when words end in a diphthong or for the conjunction
    - Words like *iglesia* when capitalized no longer change *I* to *Y*
  - Confirms and codifies the changes made in the DdA and the conferences
  - Use of accent to break diphthong established (no longer assumed ever except for two-syllable words consisting of a single consonant and two vowels, in which case you accent the second vowel if it's monosyllabic and the first is a weak vowel)
  - Inverted question and exclamation marks now standard, but in series of questions, only one inverted before the first question, and a closing one for each question.
  - Two styles of enclosing marks, () and []
  - Splitting hyphen recognized as both - and =
- **1820** [Ortografía de la lengua castellana](http://books.google.com/books?id=UicSAAAAIAAJ&dq=Ortograf%C3%ADa%20de%20la%20lengua%20castellana%201820&pg=PP9#v=onepage&q&f=false)
- **1870** Prontuario de ortografía de la lengua castellana en preguntas y respuestas

  - Duplication of *r* to *rr* in the interior of compound or prefixed words.
- **1952** Nuevas normas de prosodia y ortografía
- **1969** Ortografía
- **1974** Ortografía
- **1999** Ortografía de la lengua española

  - Alphabetic sorting of the letters *ch* and *ll* to be considered two separate letters rather than one
- **2010** Ortografía de la lengua española

  - Written accents to be used exclusively for phonetics and not semantics
  - *ch* and *ll* removed from the alphabet
  - Single name for letters (B *be*, I *i*, V *uve*, W *uve doble*, Y *ye*)
- **2012** Ortografía básica de la lengua española

One of the biggest changes is evident from the spelling of the first to second editions — the *th* and *ph* digraphs were reduced to *t* and *f*.  There were some other modifications made on accents on words (*ia* used to always be with hiatus similar to modern Portuguese), a bit with *b/v*.

Comment: (Note to all: I'm going to be updating this post as I read through the different editions, except for the 1952-1999 ones that I don't have access to)

Comment: +1 for you highly detailed answer. You put quite **a lot** of work into it.

Comment: @Diego still working on it  :)  — but probably needs to wait for tomorrow.   It's amazing just how much thought is put into the orthography for Spanish.

Comment: Also there's a few things that seem odd, where the Academy's history of itself seems to not line up with the books I read, so hopefully as I go along I'll clean that up.

Comment: *CH* and *LL* were added twice? 1754 and 1803?

Comment: @Flimzy According to the 1820 intro, yes :-) My guess is that was when they made their first appearance in the dictionary under separate headings.  When I finish going through the orthographies one by one I'll update.

Comment: @Flimzy It seems indeed that that is when they were first sorted differently.  So in 1992 they went back to the pre-1803 style of them being letters, but just not sorted as such.  And of course in 2010 they remove their status as letters entirely :(

Comment: @guifa Your answer is going beyond my initial hopes when I asked the question.  I love it!  Let me know when you are finished so I can mark it as the official answer.

Comment: @guifa Four months later, I think I will mark your answer as the official answer.  You are welcome to modify it some more if/when you finish your research.