# ¿Por qué "había" lleva tilde? ¿Acaso no se pronunciaría de la misma forma si no la tuviese?

Tags: acentuación

Según lo que he leído "había" lleva tilde para romper el diptongo pero en caso de que la palabra no tuviese tilde, no se sobreentiende que si no lleva tilde en la "a" se prenunciara igual a que si tuviese tilde en la silaba "bi"?
Ya que si la silaba tónica fuera la ultima debería llevar tilde en la "a"

Comment: That symbol is called a tilde in Spanish?!? In English, "~" is a tilde, and the symbol you show is called "acute"; if it is really "tilde" in espanol, it's another case of a false friend/point of confusion waiting to happen.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Yeah, in Spanish the word tilde usually refers to the acute but it can also mean the English tilde (~) [here's the official definition of tilde in Spanish](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=tilde)

Comment: @Jorge, ¿ves la diferencia entre `hacia` y `hacía`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Si no llevara tilde deberíamos entender que la palabra tiene dos sílabas:

> ha - bia

Como esta nueva palabra termina en vocal sin tilde, entonces es una palabra *grave* (o *llana*), acentuada en la penúltima sílaba. Habría que pronunciarla así:

> [**á**][bia]

como en "rabia".

Considera estas dos frases con ejemplos equivalentes. La negrita indica la sílaba acentuada:

> Mi madre es una mujer muy **sa**bia.
>
> Yo no sa**bí**a la respuesta a su pregunta.

Si quitaramos la tilde del segundo ejemplo ambas palabras se escribirían igual, pero en realidad se pronuncian distinto y significan cosas distintas.

Comment: Probablemente cabe notar que las reglas de acentuación en español han ido cambiándose tras los años, cosa que me hace recordar que todavía no he terminado la respuesta aquí: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/10328/editions-of-spanish-orthographies/10329#10329

Answer (score 0):

Dicen que si una palabra es grave y termina en "n" , "s" o en "vocal" no lleva tilde pero qué pasa con "había", "hacía" y todas esas palabras.

Se lo agradecería mucho ya que mantengo un debate desde hace dos semanas con una amiga.