# Why is the "í" accented in conditional mood conjugations?

Tags: conjugación, condicional, diacríticos

Consider the following [reference](http://www.spanish411.net/Spanish-Accent-Marks-Special-Characters.asp):

> If there isn't a written accent mark, every Spanish word that ends in a vowel, an "-n," or an "-s" has the stress fall on the second-to-last syllable (the "penultimate" syllable)

However, if this rule is so, why is the "i" accented in the majority (if not all) of verbs when they are conjugated into the conditional tense. For example:

- Mostaría
- Echaría

Comment: Here is a similar question, might help you: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/12382/por-qu%C3%A9-hab%C3%ADa-lleva-tilde-acaso-no-se-pronunciar%C3%ADa-de-la-misma-forma-si-no

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because without the accent, the *ia* forms a diphthong resulting in the syllabification mos-tra-ria or e-cha-ria, and then the default stress would be on the *tra* or *cha* syllable instead of on the *i*.

Accents can also break up diphthongs when the weak vowel is also the stressed one, which is the case in verbs in the conditional tense.

Comment: It's worth noting that `U` and `I` are the weakest vowels in Spanish.