# ¿Qué pasó con el uso de la preposición "a" a principios del siglo XX?

Tags: preposiciones, historia

Jugando con Ngram a ver si podía encontrar la palabra más usada del español (va ganando ***[de](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=de&year_start=1600&year_end=2015&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cde%3B%2Cc0)*** con un 5,8% de apariciones), me encuentro con la siguiente gráfica cuando busqué la preposición *a*:

[image: Evolución de la preposición "a"]

Así que la pregunta es simple: ¿qué pasó hacia 1908 que hizo que el uso de la preposición *a* se disparara del 0,2% al 1,6%?

Comment: Probablemente tenga que ver con la regularización de la ortografía castellana: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%2Cá&year_start=1600&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cá%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Yay ¡Qué buena! Si redactas una respuesta te la acepto.

Comment: Prometo hacerlo cuando tenga un momentillo. Mientras tanto, si alguien tiene buenas referencias, ¡que no dude en dar una respuesta! (tampoco es que por hacer un comentario haya monopolizado la respuesta :D). Por cierto, esto me recuerda a [una pregunta similar](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/327087/the-f-word-in-n-gram-viewer) con Google Ngrams en ELU.

Comment: Es precisamente un cambio en la ortografía. Originalmente la proposición no llevaba tilde, luego sí, y luego no nuevo jaja. Las pocas sin tilde en el siglo XIX serían probablemente de nombres o en listas o ecuaciones

Comment: Y de hecho mirando en el [Mapa de diccionarios de la RAE](http://web.frl.es/ntllet/SrvltGUILoginNtlletPub) se ve que para _a_ como preposición (segunda entrada) muchas de sus acepciones no aparecen hasta 1925. La búsqueda de _á_ no da resultados, pero probablemente daría un resultado inverso siguiendo con lo descubierto por @Yay

Comment: @fedorqui Según veo, hasta la edición de 1884 la *á* iba acentuada, y en el de 1925 se pasa a *a*. Será esa la reforma que habrá habido, porque encaja perfectamente con el NGram.

Comment: @Yay ah, ¡cierto! No me fijé en que al seleccionar la [entrada _a_](http://web.frl.es/ntllet/SrvltGUIForAceps?numReg=1&sec=1.0.1.0.&V_PUBLIC=V_PUBLIC) se ve todo esto. Incluso hay un icono que indica "diagrama de variantes gráficas" en el que a, a_1 y á convergen en _a_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Contesto para intentar expandir los interesantes comentarios a la pregunta</sub>

Tal y como [comentó Yay](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17278/qu%C3%A9-pas%C3%B3-con-el-uso-de-la-preposici%C3%B3n-a-a-principios-del-siglo-xx#comment23300_17278), su origen tiene que ver con el hecho de que la ortografía castellana se regularizó. El Ngram que enlaza da buena muestra de ello, produciéndose un desplazamiento de *á* a *a* de forma abrupta hacia 1910:

[image]

Mirando la [respuesta canónica de guifa a Editions of Spanish Orthographies?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/10329/1674) vemos que inicialmente la preposición *a* se escribía siempre con tilde:

> - **1741** [Orthographía española](http://www.rae.es/sites/default/files/Ortografia_RAE_1741_reducida.pdf)
>
>   - Preposition *á* and conjunctions *é*, *ó*, *ú* always accented.

En esta respuesta no veo dónde se dejó de acentuar. Para ello recurrimos al [Mapa de diccionarios académicos](http://web.frl.es/ntllet/SrvltGUILoginNtlletPub) (contiene las ediciones de 2001, 1992, 1925, 1884, 1817 y 1780). Buscando por *a* podemos acceder a una imagen que representa la evolución de la escritura de esta preposición:

[image]

Para verlo con más claridad, podemos seleccionar la palabra [*á*](http://web.frl.es/ntllet/SrvltGUIForAceps?numReg=1&sec=1.0.1.0.&V_PUBLIC=V_PUBLIC) (ojo, hay que tener una sesión abierta para que el enlace funcione). Allí vemos que en 1780 había un total de 31 entradas para *á*, principalmente para referirse a la preposición. En 1817 estas entradas se mantienen, en 1884 hay cierta reordenación pero se conservan. Sin embargo, en 1925 ya se encuentran en la entrada de [*a*](http://web.frl.es/ntllet/SrvltGUIForAceps?numReg=0&sec=1.0.1.0.&V_PUBLIC=V_PUBLIC). Por tanto, vemos un traslado de acepciones de *á* a *a* entre 1884 y 1925.

Desconozco qué pasó entre esos años, pues en la respuesta de guifa que mencioné arriba no hay ninguna entrada entre esos dos años. Ved los comentarios aquí abajo en los que Carlos Alejo apunta a la Gramática de la lengua castellana número 25 de 1908.

Comment: ¡Gracias por responder! Como comentario, yo en el mapa de diccionarios veo que la preposición _á_ se mantiene en el diccionario de 1884, y es en el de 1925 cuando ya es _a_. Investigando por mi cuenta, veo que existe una edición de la _Gramática de la lengua castellana_, la número 25, [que es precisamente de 1908](http://www.rae.es/sites/default/files/Tabla_ediciones_Gramatica.pdf), que es cuando en la gráfica comienza el subidón. Posiblemente fuera entonces cuando se regularizó el idioma.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo oh, precisamente estaba con eso ahora mismo, pues no me encajaban las fechas que yo mencionaba con las que se ven en el Ngram. Lo reviso y edito para mejorarlo, ¡gracias!

Comment: He preguntado a la RAE, pero me dicen que no responden a preguntas de corte histórico, que sólo responden sobre el español actual. Soy incapaz de encontrar el texto de la gramática de 1908 (edición 25) o la de 1909 (edición 26) por Internet, aunque se pueden encontrar ejemplares en bibliotecas o en librerías (el precio varía entre los 15 y los 33 euros). La respuesta tiene que estar ahí.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo tampoco yo lo conseguí tras buscar un buen rato en Google Books. Lo mismo algún usuario académico como guifa tiene acceso a él.

Comment: ¡Invoquemos pues a @guifa!

Comment: Usando el Nuevo Tesoro Lexicográfico en la web de la RAE se puede reducir el intervalo a entre 1902 (última aparición de la preposición "á" en un diccionario) y 1914 (primera aparición de "a" como preposición).

Comment: @CarlosAlejo caramba, interesante. A ver si puedo sacar algo de tiempo para editar la respuesta con este contenido.