# ¿Cuándo se incorporó la Ñ al abecedario como letra con entidad propia?

Tags: ortografía, historia, alfabeto, diacríticos

Los documentos de la RAE no paran de esconder sorpresas. La última me la llevé ojeando la primera [Orthographía española](http://www.rae.es/recursos/ortografia/primera-ortografia) de 1741, en la cual descubrí lo siguiente en el apartado dedicado a las letras que componían por entonces el abecedario español:

[image: Abecedario]

Vale que faltase por entonces la W, pero ¿y la Ñ? Buscando un poco más adelante las peculiaridades de cada letra, encontré lo siguiente:

[image]

Es decir, que por aquel entonces la Ñ no se distinguía de la N más de lo que hoy en día distinguimos la A de la Á, o la U de la Ü. Era simplemente una N con una tilde encima. Así pues, ¿cuándo se le dio a la Ñ entidad de letra independiente y digna de ser incluida en el abecedario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pesar de que tratados de ortografía anteriores, como el de Nebrija de 1523, incluían la Ñ en el alfabeto, efectivamente la primera edición de la ortografía de la RAE la omite, contando pues un total de 25 letras en el mismo.

En la segunda edición, que se pasó a llamar *[Ortografia de la lengua Castellana](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_f89MAAAAcAAJ)* (publicada en 1754), se puede leer lo siguiente en la página 16:

> En la primera impresion de este Tratado se dexaron de añadir la *ch*, la *ll* y la *ñ* que son letras propias nuestras; pero ahora, reflexionado este punto, ha parecido que sin ellas está defectuoso el Abecedario: porque ninguna de las otras representa en lo escrito el sonido que atribuimos á cada una de estas, y distinguen las voces *chasco*, *llanto*, *año*, especialmente quando la diversidad de las letras no consiste tanto en la figura, como en la diferencia de su pronunciacion.

Por tanto, el abecedario tras esta corrección queda con 28 letras:

[image: Abecedario]

Sin embargo, este cambio no se vio reflejado en el diccionario de la RAE hasta su edición de 1803. Hasta entonces, las palabras que empezaban por Ñ se mostraban al final de la sección correspondiente a la N, pero no contaban con sección propia. De hecho, si accedemos al [NTTLE](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/nuevo-tesoro-lexicografico) y buscamos "o", la entrada correspondiente a la edición de 1791 del diccionario dice:

> O. Décimaquinta letra de nuestro alfabeto [...].

no habiendo en este diccionario una entrada propia para la letra Ñ, que sí existe en la siguiente edición, de 1803:

> Ñ. Decimaséptima letra de nuestro alfabeto [...].

Nótese el cambio en la numeración, dado que el diccionario de 1803 fue el primero que en el que se aplicó la inclusión de la *ch*, *ll* y *ñ* (cambio que la ortografía ya había contemplado medio siglo antes). De hecho, la explicación de este cambio en la forma de ordenar las palabras ocupa gran parte del [prólogo de dicha edición de 1803 (PDF)](http://www.rae.es/sites/default/files/Prologo_de_la_edicion_de_1803.pdf).

Comment: Fantástica investigación para tu propia pregunta, Carlos, eres un poco como Messi: centras y rematas :) Me hace pensar que podríamos tener alguna pregunta de recopilación de estos hechos, del tipo [Editions of Spanish Orthographies?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/10328/1674)

Comment: @fedorqui la respuesta de guifa a aquella pregunta es fantástica, de hecho la tenía ya votada. Volviéndola a leer me doy cuenta de que incluye la primera mitad de mi respuesta (buenísimo su comentario de "ups, que nos las habíamos olvidado"). ¿Qué pregunta de recopilación sugieres? ¿Algo del tipo "cómo ha evolucionado el abecedario español desde que comenzó la RAE"?

Comment: (Cachis, no encuentro ese comentario que dices...) El título que comentas suena muy bien, sería interesante poner una tabla resumen y luego ir añadiendo detalles entre todos.

Comment: @fedorqui: en la respuesta de guifa, tercera línea de los cambios de 1754:  Added letters CH che, LL elle, and Ñ eñe to the alphabet (**“oops we left them out before”, they said**)