# ¿Desde cuándo tenemos las actuales reglas de acentuación?

Tags: ortografía, historia, acentuación

En el DPD podemos encontrar las reglas de acentuación bajo la entrada de [tilde](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Adwesaq4ND64VT09xQ):

> 1.1. Polisílabos. La acentuación gráfica de las palabras de más de una sílaba se atiene a las reglas siguientes:
>
> 1.1.1. Las palabras agudas (→ acento, 1.2a) llevan tilde cuando terminan en *-n*, en *-s* o en vocal: *balón*, *compás*, *café*, *colibrí*, *bonsái*; pero si terminan en -*s* precedida de otra consonante, se escriben sin tilde: *zigzags*, *robots*, *tictacs*. Tampoco llevan tilde las palabras agudas que terminan en -*y*, pues esta letra se considera consonante a efectos de acentuación: *guirigay*, *virrey*, *convoy*, *estoy*.
>
> 1.1.2. Las palabras llanas (→ acento, 1.2b) llevan tilde cuando no terminan en *-n*, en *-s* o en vocal: *clímax*, *hábil*, *tándem*. También se acentúan cuando terminan en *-s* precedida de otra consonante: *bíceps*, *cómics*, *fórceps*; y cuando terminan en *-y*, pues esta letra se considera consonante a efectos de acentuación: *póney*, yóquey.
>
> 1.1.3. Las palabras esdrújulas (→ acento, 1.2c) y sobresdrújulas (→ acento, 1.2d) siempre llevan tilde: *cántaro*, *mecánica*, *cómetelo*, *llévesemelo*.

Sin embargo, en el Diccionario de Autoridades encontré una texto donde estas reglas debieron ser distintas:

> [Diccionario de Autoridades - Tomo V (1737)](http://web.frl.es/DA.html)
>
> PERJUDICAR. v. a. Hacer daño, causar pérdida o perjuicio a otro. Viene del Latino *Praejudicare*. Latín. *Nocêre*. *Damnum inferre*. ALCAZ. Chron. Decad. 3. Año 1. cap. 1. §. 1. Por lo qual no llevaba bien algunas fundaciones que admitia el Santo, cuyo pié de renta no alcanzaba al sustento preciso de sus moradores, sin el recurso a las limosnas, cuya solicitúd perjudicaba a los ministérios.

Acá tenemos varias palabras para las que no se usaría tilde según las reglas actuales, o al revés:

- admitia
- pié
- solicitúd
- ministérios

¿Cuáles eran las reglas en ese entonces? ¿Cuándo evolucionaron a las que conocemos actualmente?

Comment: Relacionada: _[¿Qué revisiones ha tenido la ortografía española?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/10328/12637)_ Algunos de los cambios en las reglas de acentuación se pueden ver ahí.

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿te refieres a las reglas básicas o a todas las reglas? Lo digo porque la RAE está constantemente cambiando las reglas (como cuando les dio por quitar la tilde en palabras como _solo_ o los pronombres demostrativos _este, ese, aquel_). Si te refieres al conjunto de todas las reglas de acentuación, yo diría que desde la última edición de la _Ortografía_ del 2010. Si te refieres a las básicas (acentuación de palabras polisílabas agudas, llanas y esdrújulas), habría que mirarlo.

Comment: @Charlie me refiero a las reglas básicas  (acentuación de palabras polisílabas agudas, llanas y esdrújulas).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estoy revisando las ediciones de la Ortografía de la RAE. Debo decir que las reglas de acentuación de la primera edición eran un auténtico guirigay, aunque para las posteriores ediciones se cambiaron un poco, las cuales fueron las siguientes durante bastante tiempo (las básicas al menos):

- Nunca acentuar monosílabos salvo si tienen más de dos significados (de/dé).
- Las agudas se acentúan si acaban en vocal.
- Las llanas se acentúan si acaban en consonante.
- Las esdrújulas y sobreesdrújulas se acentúan siempre.

Estas reglas se mantuvieron hasta hace relativamente poco. Por ejemplo, en las Gramáticas de 1870 y 1874 (durante un tiempo se dejaron de publicar ediciones de la Ortografía, que se integró en la Gramática) vemos que la regla es parecida a la actual, pero con diferencias:

- Las agudas se acentúan si acaban en vocal, o si acaban en *s* porque son plurales, o si acaban en *s* o *n* porque sean tiempos verbales que acaban así. De esta forma, palabras como *compás* no se acentuaban al no ser plurales aunque acabaran en *s*.
- Las llanas se acentúan si acaban en consonante y no son plurales ni verbos: *miéntras*, *Cármen*, *entónces*, etc.

No consigo acceder a los textos de Gramáticas y Ortografías posteriores, pero podemos hacer una prueba sencilla, con los datos que tenemos hasta ahora: buscar *compás* en las ediciones del DLE usando el NTLLE y ver cuándo cambió su acentuación. Y entonces salta la sorpresa: en la edición de 1822 está sin tilde, y en la de 1832 con tilde, sigue así hasta 1869 en la que la tilde vuelve a desaparecer, y en 1884 la vuelve a tener. Y así se queda ya hasta hoy.

Probemos con *entonces*, que debería ir acentuada. Con tilde en 1803, sin tilde desde 1817 hasta 1852, vuelta con tilde en 1869 y sin tilde desde 1884. Idéntica evolución sufrió *mientras*.

Así pues, parece que las ediciones del DLE y de la Ortografía no iban muy de la mano que digamos. Fue en 1869 cuando se pusieron serios e hicieron una versión del diccionario que iba acorde con las reglas de acentuación que ellos mismos promulgaban, y en algún momento entre esa fecha y 1884 la regla de acentuar las agudas acabadas en *n* o *s* se extendió a todas la palabras, y no solo a plurales y tiempos verbales.

Si miramos la [cronología de la RAE en el siglo XIX](http://www.rae.es/la-institucion/historia/siglo-xix), vemos lo siguiente entre las dos ediciones mencionadas del DLE:

> -1869. Aparece la undécima edición del Diccionario de la lengua castellana.
>   -1870. Se inicia la publicación del Prontuario de ortografía de la lengua castellana en preguntas y respuestas. Tuvo treinta y una ediciones, la última de 1931. Las tres últimas cambiaron en el título la expresión lengua castellana por lengua española.
>   -1870. Duodécima edición de la Gramática de la lengua castellana.
>   -1874. Decimotercera edición de la Gramática de la lengua castellana.
>   -1875. El 2 de diciembre Juan de la Pezuela y Ceballos (silla a) es elegido decimoquinto director.
>   -1878. Decimocuarta edición de la Gramática de la lengua castellana.
>   -1880. Decimoquinta edición de la Gramática de la lengua castellana.
>   -1883. Decimosexta edición de la Gramática de la lengua castellana.
>   -1884. Duodécima edición del Diccionario de la lengua castellana.

Ya sabemos que hasta 1874 al menos, las reglas aún no eran las actuales. Y justo en 1875 la Academia cambia de director. Resulta muy probable que fuera este nuevo director quien decidiera cambiar las reglas, simplificándolas para no tener que depender de si una palabra era plural o tiempo verbal para saber si acentuarla o no, y así hacerlas ya idénticas a como las tenemos hoy, aunque no he podido encontrar nada que lo corrobore. En todo caso, sabemos que dicho cambio debió aparecer publicado en las ediciones de la Gramática entre 1878 y 1883.