# Ortografía de "concilio"

Tags: ortografía, pronunciación

Hoy aprendí que en la ortografía española de "concilio" no hay acento escrito. Esto me sorprende, porque en portugués se escribe "concílio", que corresponde exactamente a la pronunciación (acento en la antepenúltima sílaba "ci", que entonces debe ser indicada). ¿De donde viene esta diferencia ? ¿ Es porque la pronunciación es diferente ?

Comment: Las reglas para el español dicen que las palabras llanas acabadas en vocal no llevan tilde. Por tanto "concilio" (acentuada en "ci") no la lleva. Tal vez podríamos crear una pregunta genérica (si no la hay ya) que explique cuáles son las reglas básicas de acentuación del español.

Comment: En [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/22890/12637) tienes resumidas las reglas básicas de acentuación.

Comment: Las reglas ortográficas que rigen la acentuación gráfica de palabras agudas y graves son exactamente opuestas entre español y portugués.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [¿Desde cuándo tenemos las actuales reglas de acentuación?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/22890/desde-cu%c3%a1ndo-tenemos-las-actuales-reglas-de-acentuaci%c3%b3n) Resume las reglas básicas de acentuación

Comment: user673452, ¿estás más que nada preguntando cómo llegó a haber esta diferencia de pronunciación, tal vez? // Aprovecho para darte la bienvenida al sitio.

Comment: @Gustavson ¿Qué es una palabra "grave" ? Solo conozco palabras agudas, llanas, esdrújulas o sobreesdrújulas.

Comment: *Grave* and *llana* are synonyms.

Comment: @aparente001 they are indeed. **[grave](https://dle.rae.es/grave)**: 9. adj. Fon. Dicho de una palabra: **llana**. Today I learned.

Comment: @Charlie - Oh.  Which one weren't you familiar with before?  I don't remember which one I learned first -- the truth is I'm not great with terminology and the only one that truly stuck with me was *sobreesdrújula* because it's such a fun word.

Comment: @aparente001 I was unfamiliar with "grave" (used as a synonym of "llana", of course).