# ¿Por qué escribimos "otrora" y no "otrhora"?

Tags: ortografía, letras

Me fijé hoy en la palabra *otrora*, un cultismo que hoy es la *Palabra del día* del DLE:

> [**otrora**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RLQWGdT)
>   `De otra hora.`
>
> 1. adv. cult. En otro tiempo, en un tiempo pasado.

Dado que viene de otra y hora, ¿por qué se cae la "h" y no se dice "otrhora"?

Inicialmente pensé que sería una palabra antigua y que aplicaría lo explicado en [Revisions of Spanish orthography / ¿Qué revisiones ha tenido la ortografía española?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/10329/1674):

> - **1754** [Ortografía de la lengua castellana](http://bivaldi.gva.es/es/consulta/registro.cmd?id=6648)
>
>   - Removed the “erudite” spellings <sub>(their words in the 1803 intro, not mine)</sub>, mainly *th*, *rh*, *ch* /k/ and *ph* but not completely

Por lo cual la *rh* se habría eliminado. Sin embargo, luego vi que *otrora* no es tan antigua, en 1754 faltaban casi doscientos años para que esta palabra se incluyera en el diccionario, que el NTLLE nos marca en 1936:

> Otrora. adv. m. En otro tiempo.
>   <sub>1936 ACADEMIA USUAL</sub>

Luego uno diría: vale, es que la forma *rh* no puede habitar en el idioma castellano. Pero es que si en el DLE buscamos "rh" marcando "contiene" encontramos una lista no desdeñable:

*aclorhidria* / *aclorhídrico, ca* / *carhuacino, na* / *clorhidrato* / *clorhídrico, ca* / *dírham* / *dírhem* / *fluorhídrico* / *hiperclorhidria* / *hiperclorhídrico, ca* / *hiperhidrosis* / *hipoclorhidria* / *hipoclorhídrico, ca* / *parhelia* / *parhelio* / *parhilera* / *pirhuín* / *poderhabiente* / *superhéroe, ína* / *superheroína* / *superheterodino* / *superhombre* / *superhumeral* / *tarhui*.

Por todo ello, mi duda inicial persiste: ¿por qué escribimos *otrora* y no *otrhora*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si te fijas, casi todas las palabras de la lista tienen algo en común, y es que la parte de cada palabra que empieza por *h* proviene de un sufijo independiente: *-hídrico*, *-hidrosis*, *-helio*, *-habiente*, *-héroe*... y eso hace que al separar las sílabas de cada palabra se permita dejar esa parte aislada: *clor-hí-dri-co*, *po-der-ha-bien-te*, *su-per-hé-ro-e*, y no *clo-rhí-dri-co*, *po-de-rha-bien-te* o *su-pe-rhé-ro-e*. Incluso las que provienen de otro idioma, como *pirhuín* o *tarhui*, si miras en sus definiciones la primera equivale a *pirgüín*, y con esa pronunciación se separaría así: *pir-huín* y no *pi-rhuín*. Y la segunda procede de *tarwi*, que haría que su pronunciación fuese *tar-hui*.

En el caso de *otrora* no hay otra forma de separar la palabra que no sea *o-tro-ra*. Si fuese con *h* tendríamos una sílaba *trho*, que es lo que no se permite dado el actual ideal de correspondencia biunívoca entre grafemas y fonemas. Cito la *Ortografía 2010*:

> [...] el ideal de correspodencia biunívoca entre grafemas y fonemas ha estado muy presente en la configuración del sistema ortográfico del español y ha guiado la toma de no pocas decisiones de gran calado [...]. A ello responde, por ejemplo, la decisión [...] de suprimir la *ç* para representar el fonema /z/ [...]; o la tomada en la ortografía académica de 1754 de eliminar las grafías latinizantes *ch*, *ph*, *rh* y *th*, sustituidas, respectivamente, por *c* o *qu*, *f*, *r* y *t* [...].

Es decir, que no podemos representar un sonido *tro* usando otra sílaba que no sea esta, para no romper la correspondencia entre grafemas y fonemas.

En todo caso, si esto no es suficiente, recordemos que la RAE simplemente se limita a registrar la expresión escrita. Si buscamos en el CORDE encontramos multitud de casos de *otrora* pero ninguno de *othrora*, por lo que la primera fue la voz que registró.

Comment: La clave de la respuesta está en lo que comentas de _es lo que no se permite_. ¿Entonces la "limpia" de 1754 se convirtió en regla y previno o recomendó no usar _rh_?

Comment: @fedorqui te amplío la respuesta para aclarar ese punto. :-)

Comment: Eres un crá ;-)